# Calculated column to show negative number as zero

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I have the below formula in a calculated column, which in some instances will return the number as a negative number (eg. -1234) how do get the formula to show the negative number as 0.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date incident closed waiting QA]),"",[Number of days incident open]-28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to nest an additional `IF` in there. So something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date incident closed waiting QA]),"",IF(([Number of days incident open]-28) < 0, 0, [Number of days incident open]-28))
```